# HoughLineP Segmentation Fault OpenCV

Tags: qt, opencv, unix, segmentation-fault

I am using Unix and delevoped a program that run without problems under Windows.

When running under unix I get a segmentation fault at the HoughlineP operation:

vector lines;
  HoughLinesP(image, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, a, b, c );

variables a, b, c are decleared in the constructor and later on changed by some sliders of the gui.

vector lines is empty and should be filled by the HoughlinesP function but liked described the function fails.

Is this a special unix problem?

I haven't find any solutions on the web?

imageanlyzer.h:

```
vector<Vec4i> m_lines;

ImageAnalyzer::ImageAnalyzer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
m_performAnalysis = false;

m_lowThresh = 74;
m_rho = 1;
m_highThresh = 205;
m_threshold = 20;
m_minLineLength = 16;
m_maxLineGap = 16;
m_blurSize = 3;
m_adptTreshSize = 33;
m_dilationSize = 1;
m_erodeSize = 1;
m_adptTreshC = -15;
m_heading = 260;

m_matchingValue = 0;

}
```

the problem occurs here:

```
void ImageAnalyzer::extractLines()
{
// Probalistic Hough Transform
HoughLinesP(getCanny4HoughImg(), m_lines, (double)m_rho, CV_PI/180, m_threshold, (double)m_minLineLength, (double)m_maxLineGap);
}
```

The getCanny4HoughImg() returns in image. I checked the this already.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share some (more) code or it will be hard for others to help you.

Comment: I watched the system. Having a ram of 8 Gbyte and a swap of 14Gbyte the code crashes when reaching full 8gbyte ram und 3.1 gybte of swap. I added ram to a total of 16 gbyte and the code crashes at 8 gybte ram and almost none swap!